# Regular expression for strings, which are no ended with a specified substring

Tags: javascript, regex

Please advice a regular expression to find all string which are not ended with ".pdf".
So, it should find stings "some string" and "some stringpdf", but not the strings like "some string.pdf"

Thanks,
Aleksey Asiutin

Comment: If that's all you need, you can use a regexp to find .pdf-ended strings, and then reject them when they match, and accept the rest

Comment: @NannuoLei Don't even think about abusing regex for this purpose.

Comment: @Jack you're right, regexp is too mucch for such small task, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to test **individual** string's you can use this regex

```
/^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$/
```

---

If there are multiple string's to be matched within the string,you can use

```
/(\s|^)(?![^\s]+\.pdf(\s|$))[^\s]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the regex

```
/^(?!.*\.pdf$).*/
```

example:

```
var r =  /^(?!.*\.pdf$).*/;
r.test("some string");     //true
r.test("some stringpdf");  //true
r.test("some string.pdf"); //false
```

in actually, I recommend the suggestion from @Nannuo Lei.